# Add hash # to UrlGenerator

Tags: php, url, symfony

I'm looking for a working solution, to pass hashes `#` to symfony's [`UrlGenerator`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.html) class.

According to the [documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#method_generate), you can only pass parameters, but no special values?

```
$this->router->generate('my_route', array('#' => '/!_ugly_hash_value'), true);
```

Example output:

```
http://www.joe-schmoe-at-home.tld/special_link#/!_ugly_hash_value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding hash to url try to use this:

```
print $this->router->generate('my_route') ."#!_ugly_hash_value";
```

Comment: PHP is not working with hash. Hash is the HTML parameter. And it's no a reasons to abstract this with OOP.

Comment: @Viktor in this respect this makes sense. Thank you, however.